# Solved: Python: Cropped Image is off by one pixel

Tags: python, image, shapes, index-error

I'm writing a programm to analyse cells from mikroskopy images. At one point I need to crop a binary mask ("membranal") so it has the same shape as the image section I would like to use the mask on ("section"). Both are numpy arrays, so I slice the mask with [y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max] with y_max and x_max based on section.shape.
For some masks this works just fine and for some the shape is off by one pixel, which causes an IndexError later.

So why do some masks don't have the shape I just defined one line before?
Is this some weird internal rounding error or what do I do wrong?

A code snipped looks like this:

```
for counter, event in enumerate(image_event_list):
    [...calculating x/y coordinates and stuff...]
    section = image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
    membranal_cropped = membranal[0:section.shape[0], 0:section.shape[1]]
    print("Event:", counter, "Section Shape:", section.shape, "Membranal_cropped Shape:", membranal_cropped.shape)
    try:
        section_intensity = np.mean(section[membranal_cropped>0])
        print("No error, working fine.")
    except IndexError:
        print("IndexError")
```

Output would be like this:

- Event: 4 Section Shape: (111, 93, 3) Membranal_cropped Shape: (111, 92)
  IndexError
- Event: 6 Section Shape: (85, 134, 3) Membranal_cropped Shape: (85, 134)
  No error, working fine.
- Event: 8 Section Shape: (158, 169, 3) Membranal_cropped Shape: (158, 169)
  No error, working fine.
- Event: 10 Section Shape: (74, 97, 3) Membranal_cropped Shape: (74, 97)
  No error, working fine.
- Event: 13 Section Shape: (109, 106, 3) Membranal_cropped Shape: (109, 105)
  IndexError
- Event: 17 Section Shape: (94, 83, 3) Membranal_cropped Shape: (93, 82)
  IndexError
- Event: 23 Section Shape: (82, 110, 3) Membranal_cropped Shape: (82, 110)
  No error, working fine.

Sorry that I can't provide the full code.

Comment: The problem is in the code generating the `membranal`, when you crop it it is already smaller by this one pixel and even tho you crop properly it won't work:
`>>> [1,2,3][0:100] is [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: You're right. The original "membranal" array was in some cases already to small. Thank you very much!